# problems printing some characters

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

i have the following code:

```
'^XA^CI28^CWZ,E:TT0003M_.FNT^FS^XZ^XA^FWN^FO70,50^A0,30,25^FH^FD'.function_parse($name).'^FS^FO70,90^BY2^B3,,100^FD' . $product['value'] . '^FS^XZ';

function_parse($name):
    $str = str_replace('Θ','_CE_98',$str);
        $str = str_replace('Κ','_CE_9A',$str);
        $str = str_replace('Μ','_CE_9C',$str);
        $str = str_replace('Ν','_CE_9D',$str);
        $str = str_replace('Ξ','_CE_9E',$str);
        $str = str_replace('Ο','_CE_9F',$str);
        $str = str_replace('ρ','_CF_81',$str);
        $str = str_replace('ψ','_CF_88',$str);
        $str = str_replace('ό','_CF_8C',$str);
        $str = str_replace('Ό','_CE_8C',$str);
        $str = str_replace('ύ','_cf_8d',$str);
        $str = str_replace('Ύ','_ce_8e',$str);
        $str = str_replace('ώ','_cf_8e',$str);
        $str = str_replace('Ώ','_ce_8f',$str);
        $str = str_replace('Έ','_ce_88',$str);
        $str = str_replace('Ί','_ce_8a',$str);
        return $str;
```

I have problems with the above greek characters, and the replacement i have made, returns instead of chinese letters, a ? for each such letter. What should the replacement be for these fonts?

We use a gc420t zebra printer if it is of any help

Comment: @Luuk not sure if this fits my situation... so i should use CI34 instead of C128 in my command? The example shown there is not easy for me... ^FB559,,,C,^FT30,106^A@N,23,31,TT0003M_^FH^CI17^F8^FD_text_^FS^CI. Could you please give me an example with my code shown above? ^XA^CI28^CWZ,E:TT0003M_.FNT^FS^XZ^XA^FWN^FO70,50^A0,30,25^FH^FD'.function_parse($name).'

Comment: Sorry, I do not have a zebra printer to test.

Comment: i can test, but what would you suggest i should try?

Comment: Try: http://staging.advanced-technology-group.com/?density=8&quality=grayscale&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%0A%5ECI28%0A%5ECWZ%2CE%3ATT0003M_.FNT%0A%5EFS%5EXZ%5EXA%5EFWN%5EFO70%2C50%5EA0%2C30%2C25%5EFH%5EFD_ce_8e%0A%5EFS%5EFO70%2C90%5EBY2%5EB3%2C%2C100%5EFDtestprodcuct%5EFS%5EXZ

Comment: oops, I typed `testprodcuct`, and not `testproduct`  

Comment: no worries! :) _ce_8e works on the above link, it shows correctly the Ύ letter, but not on my printer... it shows a ?

Comment: I think the comments on this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65394876/724039